# Parse complex xml in android

Tags: android

I have one aaplicaiton in which i am parsing this xml using sax parser

http://feed.dinmat.no/android_proxy.php?action=find&find=&path=Svin&amount=15&page=1

I want to parse all wine tags in this xml fro particular receipe

Please give me some idea

```
package dinmat.android.parser;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParser;
import javax.xml.parsers.SAXParserFactory;

import org.xml.sax.Attributes;
import org.xml.sax.InputSource;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.XMLReader;
import org.xml.sax.helpers.DefaultHandler;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import dinmat.android.R;
import dinmat.android.global.Global;
import dinmat.android.objects.Recipes_Wines;

public class XmlParser extends DefaultHandler
{

    public String RootElement;
    public String RecordElement;
    public String xmlURL;
    public Object mainObj;  
    public Object newObj;
    public boolean inProcess;

    public ArrayList<Object> Records = null;

    private final String TAG = "XmlParser";

    StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer(); 
    String elementName;
    String elementValue;
    String im;
    Context context;
    String NodeIDGEt;
    public XmlParser(String strURL,Object tempObj)
    {
//      xmlURL = strURL;
        Log.i("In SAXParser activity", " in XmlParser: *** ");
        mainObj = tempObj;      
        inProcess = false;
        xmlURL = strURL;

    }
    /*public XmlParser(InputStream open, Recipes tempObj) 
    {
        xmlURL = open.toString();
        mainObj = tempObj;      
        inProcess = false;
    }*/
    public ArrayList<Object> ParseFile(String rootElement ,String recordElement)
    {
        Log.i("In SAXParser activity", " in ParseFile: *** ");
        RootElement = rootElement;
        RecordElement = recordElement;      
        try
        {
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(this);
            Log.d(TAG," xmlURL ::: "+im );
            reader.parse(new InputSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(xmlURL)));
//          reader.parse(xmlURL);
//          reader.parse(new InputSource(getClass().getResourceAsStream(xmlURL)));
//      reader.parse(new InputSource(im));
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return this.Records;
    }

    public ArrayList<Object> parseUrl(String rootElement ,String recordElement)
    {
        RootElement = rootElement;
        RecordElement = recordElement;      
        try{
            URL sourceUrl = new URL(xmlURL);
            SAXParserFactory spf = SAXParserFactory.newInstance();
            SAXParser sp = spf.newSAXParser();
            XMLReader reader = sp.getXMLReader();
            reader.setContentHandler(this);

            reader.parse(new InputSource(sourceUrl.openStream()));
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return this.Records;
    }

    @Override
    public void startElement(String Uri, String localName,String qName,Attributes attributes) throws SAXException
    {
        //Log.i("In SAXParser activity", " in startElement: *** "+localName);
        elementValue = "";
        if(localName.length() > 0)
        {
            if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RootElement))
            {
                Records = new ArrayList<Object>();
            }
            else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RecordElement))
            {
                newObj = ClassUtils.newObject(mainObj);

                ClassUtils.objectMapping(newObj, localName, elementValue);

                inProcess = true;
            }
            else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("wines"))
            {
                Log.e("In SAXParser activity", " in startElement wines: *** ");
                XmlParser xmlObjBars = new XmlParser("http://feed.dinmat.no/android_proxy.php?action=find&find=&path=Svin&amount=15&page=1", new Recipes_Wines());//getAssets().open("recipes.xml").toString(), new Recipes());
                if(xmlObjBars != null)
                {
                    Global.ayyRecipesWines = xmlObjBars.parseUrl("wines", "wine");
                }
                String LocationattsValue = attributes.getValue("id");
                //Log.e("In SAXParser activity", " startElement wineselementValue :: *** "+ LocationattsValue);
                //  ArrayList   Global.AttributeValues.add(LocationattsValue);
            }
            else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("wine"))
            {
                String LocationattsValue = attributes.getValue("id");
                Global.nodeID.add(NodeIDGEt);
                Global.WineId.add(LocationattsValue);
            }   

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void characters(char[] ch,int start,int length) throws SAXException{
        elementValue+= new String(ch,start,length).trim();      
        System.out.println("Element value is "+elementValue);
    }

    @Override
    public void endElement(String Uri,String localName,String qName) throws SAXException
    {
        Log.i("In SAXParser activity", " in endElement: *** "+localName);
        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase(RecordElement)){
            Records.add(newObj);
            inProcess = false;
        }

        else if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("wines"))
        {
            Log.e("In SAXParser activity", " in wines: *** "+elementValue+"mainObj.getClass()"+mainObj.getClass());
            /*ClassUtils.objectMapping(newObj, localName, elementValue);
            Log.e("In SAXParser activity", " in image- url: *** "+elementValue+"mainObj.getClass()"+mainObj.getClass());
            System.out.println("ClassNAme"+newObj.getClass().getName());
            System.out.println("ClassNAme"+mainObj.getClass().getName());
            if(newObj.getClass().getName().equals("com.bourbon.object.Bars"))
            {
            Global.barsImage.add(elementValue);
            System.out.println("Values"+elementValue);
            }
            if(newObj.getClass().getName().equals("com.bourbon.object.Bourbons"))
            {
            Global.bourbonsImage.add(elementValue);
            System.out.println("Values"+elementValue);
            }*/
        }


        else if(inProcess){     
            ClassUtils.objectMapping(newObj, localName, elementValue);          
        }

        if(localName.equalsIgnoreCase("node_id"))
        {
            //System.out.println("Node iD"+elementValue);
            NodeIDGEt=elementValue;

        }

    }   
}
```

Comment: Post the SAX handler class code here

Answer (score 0):

i think you can just use xpath to get all your wine tags

Xpath expression :

- /recipes/recipe/wines/wine
- //wine

The first expression is faster than the second but wine node must be always in this path to be found. 
The second expression is slower (because it evaluate all nodes) but it will find all wine regarless theirs path.

http://developer.android.com/reference/javax/xml/xpath/package-summary.html

Answer (score 0):

In my opinion, a SAX parser isn't the solution for this task. SAX parsers are fine for very simple XML files, but for complex XML files, the code becomes harder to read. I would advice to use XmlBeans - assuming you have a XSD file available.

But if you are set on using SAX, here some hints:

1. `onStartElement(recipe)`: `inRecipe=true;`
2. `onStartElement(node_id)`: `if (inRecipe) { inNodeId=true; }`
3. `onEndElement(node_id)`: `if (inRecipe) { inNodeId=false; }`
4. `onCharacters(String chars)`: `if (inNodeId && (chars.equals("[desired recipe id]"))) { inDesiredRecipe=true; }`
5. `onStartElement(wines)`: `if (inDesiredRecipe) { inWines = true; }`
6. `onStartElement(wine, String id)`: `if(inWines) { wineList.add(id); }`
7. `onEndElement(wines)`: `inWines = false;`
8. `onEndElement(recipe)`: `inDesiredRecipe=false; inRecipe=false;`

Just to give you the idea how it could be done - you give the ID for the desired recipe and get a list of IDs for all the wines related to that recipe. But then you still have to get the whole Information about the wine which makes your code somehow messy, thats why I wouldn't use SAX.